# Using em units in CSS media queries is causing inconsistent results across browsers

Tags: css, media-queries, font-size

I have a set of progressive CSS media queries that follow the general formation of:

```
* {
font-size: 14pt;
}

@media screen and (min-width:85em) {
:
:
}
@media screen and (min-width:110em) {
:
:
}
```

I have 2 browsers on the same screen, exact same size (include sliders), same zoom. Chrome is hitting the 85em query and Edge is hitting the 110em query. I am assuming the em units are not the same between the browsers, but not certain why.

Is this behavior inherent to using em units?
Is there a means to standardize the em size across browsers so the same media queries are hit?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the font size in one of the browsers was set to large. It's not readily apparent on the front end, you have to look in the browser settings.